# How to draw a "blob" in Geogebra?

Tags: geogebra

I would like to draw an arbitrary open set R on the *xy*-plane in R^3 as a sort of "blob", i.e. not anything with a particular shape. Does anyone have an idea of how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Spline command](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Spline_Command) to create a "blob" that goes through those points. In 2D it can be filled, in 3D you would have to approximate it by a polygon to fill it. The following command works well if your spline is called `a`.

```
Polygon(Sequence(a(k),k,0,1,0.01))
```

Please note that this is not a programing question and is better suited for [GeoGebra help forum](https://help.geogebra.org).